# Tomcat Parallel deployment second app version

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, parallel-processing, downtime

I am trying to do parallel deployment in Tomcat to get Zero downtime.
I have read all documentation and what I understand that is almost default option just I need correct version name.

I have in webapps  folder app##001.war its running ok. I upload second version to webapps folder app##002.war second version deploy's ok, but my app version in browser do not change.

If I restart Tomcat I get new version of app, but how to get new version without restarting Tomcat. Maybe I'am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe `parallel deployment` is what you need.

It's been supported since `Tomcat 7`

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html#Parallel_deployment